# Extending content width with twentyfourteen theme

Tags: css, theme-twenty-fourteen

I'm using the twentyfourteen theme and have successfully removed the content (right) sidebar. However, I now want to stretch my content to cover the space left by removing that sidebar. I have added the following to my style.css:

```
.site-content .entry-header, .site-content .entry-content, .site-content .entry-summary, .site-content .entry-meta, .page-content { width: 100%; }
```

This increases the width of the content, but it still only covers half of the available width. How can I stretch the content to cover the full width of the page?

Comment: This is a CSS related question, which is off topic here. You should post this on the wordpress.org forum or maybe try stackoverflow

Comment: It is true that CSS is not WordPress.  But CSS is integral for nearly all WordPress customization.

Comment: >> This is a CSS related question, which is off topic here.      Can't the moderators at wordpress.org turn me away with the same argument?

Comment: I will post there.  But so I know better next time, why is this off topic?  Because it is related to CSS?

Comment: It is not off-topic just because it is about CSS. Questions which require knowledge about core internals (like the structure of a core theme) **are** on-topic.

Comment: I did, and it is clear now.

Answer (score -1):

On or around line 1043 of 2014's `style.css` you'll find several rules that set a maximum width for content. You might try removing those `max-width` settings.

I'd also add that you will be wise to make your css changes in either a child theme (check the [codex child theme page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)) or by use of a css plugin, rather than to the theme's `style.css`. That way when the theme gets updated you won't lose your changes.